# Document not defined on angular universal, changes wont get saved

Tags: angular, universal

I've searched for an answer here but I couldn't get it to work yet.

I get the following error-message when running "node dist/server.js"

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at new BrowserPlatform (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:164638:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:164682:29)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:136679:77)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:20:30)
at Object.firebase (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:123364:18)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:120467:30)
at Object../src/app/app.component.ts (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:120652:16)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:120467:30)
at Object../src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory.js (C:\cmder\Project\dist\server.js:120708:10)
```

I've read that I should put an if statement around document (and window) in that case. Which I did in the dist/server.js file:

```
var BrowserPlatform = /** @class */ (function () {
function BrowserPlatform() {
    this.emptyByteString = '';
    if(document) {this.document = document;}
    if(window) {this.window = window;}
    this.base64Available = typeof atob !== 'undefined';
}
```

Now when I run "npm run webpack:server" these changes get removed, so I'm here with the original file with just "this.document = document;" and so on and the error remains the same once I go "node dist/server.js"